# Database for Android?

Tags: android, mysql

i created an Android application but to use it properly , I need to get the objects informations from a database .There are some SQLITE definitions but as far as i see , SQLITE is related to the device which already uploaded my app. But my intention is to send informations from just a server to the all devices. The app needs to get the objects informations from the database which will be in my computer as a server , Do you know how can i handle this ? For example if I download MySQL and create a row which is like ;

```
Product A: 20
Product B: 0
```

can i get these to the app and so the app make calculations thanks to these informations?

Please let me know if i wasn't clear about my problem

Comment: mysql won't run on android. it'd run on a server, and the android device would use some kind of api to request data from the database. what that api is, is up to you.

Comment: I mean i am gonna use my own pc as a server , what should i do for this ?

Comment: You will need to host a web server on your PC and send http requests from Android to your server.

Comment: what kind of web server ?

Comment: Couchbase doesn't require a webserver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Couchbase for database needs. It is NOSQL. You use JSON objects instead of rows. It is super quick though.

http://www.couchbase.com/communities/couchbase-lite

Comment: Thanks man , did u use it as a far server ?

Comment: I not familiar with that term. Far Server?

Comment: They have a desktop version you can use. Your apps can then connect to it through http://yourip:8091 and get/set data

Comment: Thank you , i am gonna look for it , i may ask new things about it too, hope you will be around later:) And i am also open too any other new ideas :)

Comment: You can get it from here: http://www.couchbase.com/download feel free to ask question. Make sure to accept answer if this is acceptable.

Comment: Do you have any specific tutorial or example to use couchbase ?